# Every exposed port is redirecting to 8080, how do I map container port to any other rather than 8080?

Tags: wordpress, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, google-kubernetes-engine

**Issue**

I've a set of working WordPress Docker Compose containers that includes blog image and db image.

```
version: '3'
services:

  wordpress-app-db:
    build:
      context: ./mysql      
    image: wordpress-app-db:5.7-mysql
    restart: always

  php7-wordpress-app:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress-app-db
    build:
      context: ./wordpress    
    image: wordpress-app:php7    
    links:
      - wordpress-app-db
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always

volumes:
  data:
```

Now, here the above `yaml` will work with no issues at all, but when I want to change the port `8080` to some other port it simply wont work.

```
ports:
  - "<my-custom-port>:80"
```

All around the url takes me to `http://localhost:8080/`.

I'm confused of it's behaviour, I'm not able to understand why it is redirecting to `8080` if it has been mapped to other port `<my-custom-port>`.

For info, I've exposed port `80` in Dockerfile.

**Reason**

I want to do so, as I've to run this set in kubernetes cluster with `nodePort` and I can't assign it the port `8080` in `nodePort`.

Comment: Provide the logs of your container when this redirection error happens.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hello, do I understand correctly that you ran your `$ docker-compose` command on a Kubernetes node? You shouldn't do like that. If you are trying to run this resources you should convert them with a tool like Kompose or write the manifest from available examples. Adding to that, service of type `nodePort` will automatically (unless provided) assign a port from range of 30000 to 32767. Please refer to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ .

Comment: Not at all, I ran this at both - docker-compose and kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that the `siteurl` and `home` wp_options in your database are set to the correct hostname and port. I recently migrated a WordPress site from a LAMP compute instance to Kubernetes using the official WordPress images, and I experienced the exact same issue.

WordPress will perform a redirect if those values do not match your domain name.

In my case, the two fields mutated somehow during the migration, causing every request to redirect to `:8080`. They were changed to `localhost:8080`.

Comment: I'd agree with Shane here, the issue is most likely related to the wordpress config and not really the docker compose config.

Answer (score 1):

Have you cross checked the target port in your service file?
There would be 3 entries in service file.

- containerPort which maps to internal redirect something like custom port which you use in your docker-compose
- targetPort which maps to actual application port it is listening to
- nodePort which is one which you can access using <http/s>://nodeIP:nodePort

Comment: Yeah, that's what I verified at first. 

containerPort - 80
targetPort - 80
nodePort - 32252

But here, whenever I go to port 32252, it redirects me to 8080.

Comment: Then it doesn't look like docker or kubernetes issue. Something to do with internal webserver. Either php config or nginx config should help.

Might be related, here's a capture of nginx conf of that..

        location /subdir/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8010/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }